# VB.NET (Reportviewer) delimitar registros

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Tengo un programa de **VB.NET** el cual me aroja un reporte.

Al momento en el que deseo imprimir el reporte si tiene entre 9 y 12 registros lo que hace la configuracion de impresion es tomar la primera hoja de informacion y dejarla en blanco, con solo los datos de un encabezado, y en la segunda hoja ya me arroja como tal los registros consultados del reporte.

Lo que quiero es que la hoja de impresion me aroje los datos que necesito en la pagina uno y si tiene que sacar una segunda hoja de impresion que los ultimos registros queden en dicha hoja.

Comment: Estas usando crystal reports para hacer el reporte??

Comment: no, como tal estoy utilizando el reportviewer, para VB.NET 2010

Comment: Asegúrate de que la sección de detalle del informe no tiene la propiedad `KeepTogether` a `true`

Comment: esa opcion se encuentra en False pero igual al momento de tratar de imprimir la primera hoja blanca y la segunda tiene los datos, esto solo pasa con registros de 9 a 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se ajusta el tamaño de la impresion y elementos que van el la misma, y adicional se delimita el numero de registros que cargan por cada hoja.